# Webpack's deterministic modules ids optimization

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

In webpack's [doc modules id](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationmoduleids)  says that

- 'deterministic'  Short numeric ids which will not be
  changing between compilation. Good for long term caching. Enabled by
  default for production mode.

What does it mean by long term caching?

For example i have this:

```
  /***/ 812:
      /*!******************!*\
  !*** ./testA.js ***!
  \******************/
      /***/ function () {
        console.log("hello");
        /***/
      },
```

I understand that the module id 812 will remain the same during complilation changes such as importing other modules e.t.c, but i miss the point of caching role. Does it mean browser caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this guide is the answer for you, it explains in the first section why it's needed:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

> ... browsers use a technique called caching. This allows sites to load faster with less unnecessary network traffic...

> ... configuration needed to ensure files produced by webpack compilation can remain cached unless their content has changed.

Comment: Browsers use caching for seperate files, not for inline modules inside the same file.

Comment: True, but I hope you got the main point of caching modules.

Answer (score 0):

"Browsers use caching for seperate files, not for inline modules inside the same file. –
Nick
Sep 16 at 14:47"

If the module IDs change between compilations, attempts to load modules in a cached file from a newly compiled file, and vice versa would fail.

The browser may not care about internal module IDs, but those internal module IDs still need to match up for connections between webpack chunks (files).